# When do imports need to include the path?

Tags: objective-c

Sometimes I write:

```
#import <A.h>
```

Sometimes I write:

```
#import <B/A.h>
```

where B is the name of the framework.

Sometimes both work, sometimes one does not. I never understood when I have to include the path 'B' in the import.

Comment: And never `#import "A.h"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You system classes and Frameworks are commonly located at Frameworks/ system folder (all public Cocoa frameworks) or at usr/local/ (mainly headers for c-libs and some definition headers like Availability.h). Angular brackets mean the definite absolute system search path for them.

If you use some imported custom frameworks the search path depends on the build settings of your project (Header search path in Search Path section)
It is possible to define recursive search for imported classes, so both «X/Y.h» and «Y.h» will be visible by project.